# Docker "Jenkins" image can't access internet

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am using the official docker image ([found here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker))

I've used docker a lot, so I know I am running it correctly, but on **localhost**, on the **second run** I get these errors:

```
jenkins_1  | Jan 28, 2017 7:29:13 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter updateDefaultSite
jenkins_1  | WARNING: Upgrading Jenkins. Failed to update the default Update Site 'default'. Plugin upgrades may fail.
jenkins_1  | java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
jenkins_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:792)
jenkins_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
jenkins_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:789)
jenkins_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
jenkins_1  |    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
jenkins_1  |    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:171)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:180)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.updateDefaultSite(UpdateCenter.java:2193)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.install.SetupWizard.init(SetupWizard.java:168)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.install.InstallState$3.initializeState(InstallState.java:105)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setInstallState(Jenkins.java:1058)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.install.InstallUtil.proceedToNextStateFrom(InstallUtil.java:96)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:948)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:231)
```

and I get this screen ofcourse because of the errors above:
[image: Jenkins Offline]

Using a new value instead of

```
/var/jenkins_home
```

works, but again only for once, the **second time** I get the same error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what is the docker command you use to run it?

Comment: Is your host system an Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

It could be related to [issue 166](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/166), referring to [`JENKINS-31089`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31089) (not a Docker issue, but could still be relevant)

For *testing* purposes, you can try (by making a new Docker image from the one you are using):

> Replacing `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024` with `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 512` in the file `$JRE_HOME/lib/securityjava.security`.

Or (again just for testing, not a valid fix)

> edit `/etc/default/jenkins` and add the following to `JAVA_ARGS`: `-Dhudson.model.DownloadService.noSignatureCheck=true`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your docker bridge is not working properly. Delete the bridge and restart docker.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue today. It's not a problem on your computer. Is as simple as jenkins.io having their updates server down. check URL https://updates.jenkins.io/ for availability.

Answer (score 0):

I just modify update-center.json url in hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml, because i can not access https://updates.jenkins.io/. It works.

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <id>default</id>
    <url>http://mirrors.tools.huawei.com/jenkins/updates/update-center.json</url>
  </site>
</sites>
```